# How to hide a Div in HTML using angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular, hide

I want to hide a div with just titles, the div with the content is in another section

```
<div>
    <b>Entrega\</b>

    <div class="custom-control">ID da Entrega: </div>

    <div class="custom-control">ID Estoque de Origem: </div>

    <div class="custom-control">ID Itenção de Venda: </div>

    <div class="custom-control">Situação</div>

    <div class="custom-control">CNPJ Entregador</div>

    <div class="custom-control">Empresa Entregadora</div>

    <div class="custom-control">CNPJ Vendedor</div>

    <div class="custom-control">Empresa Vendedora</div>

    <div class="custom-control">DH Entrega</div>

    <div class="custom-control">DH Cancelamento</div>

    <div class="custom-control">Gerado por cancelamento? </div>

    <div class="custom-control">ID gerado por cancelamento Entrega</div>

    <div class="custom-control">ID Entrega Origem Cancel. Saída</div>

    <div class="custom-control">Motivo Cancelamento: </div>
</div>
```

to hide the div when there is no content

Comment: How do you add the content to those divs? Maybe you could use ngIf directive, for example within a ngFor, if the content is coming from an array.

Comment: the content is on  JSON file but is linked like this:
<div class="custom-control" >{{est.entregas.id_entrega}}</div>
<div class="custom-control" >{{est.entregas.id_entrega}}</div>
<div class="custom-control" >{{est.entregas.id_estoque}}</div>
<div class="custom-control" >{{est.entregas.id_intencao_venda}}</div>
<div class="custom-control" >{{est.entregas.estado_entrega}}</div>
<div class="custom-control" >{{est.entregas.cnpj_cons_entregador}}</div>
<div class="custom-control" >{{est.entregas.cons_entregador}}</div>
<div class="custom-control" >{{est.entregas.cons_vendedor}}</div>

Comment: to hide a div, you can just add *style="visibility:hidden;"*

Answer (score 1):

You could put those divs in the template like this:

```html
<div class="custom-control" *ngIf="est?.entregas?.id_entrega" >{{est.entregas.id_entrega}}</div>
```